# Code does not works on wampserver

Tags: php, json, curl, notifications, wampserver

I'm trying to send a push notification on wampserver, and it's not working.
I'ts working only when i uploads it to host server..

I already tried to delete and install again wamp.

> When the code is running on host server,
>    I'm getting this message:{"result":true} {"result":true} finished!
>   and on Wamp I doesnt get any message.

```
    <form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='text' />
<input type='submit' name='sub'/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];
$APPLICATION_ID = "xxx";
$REST_API_KEY = "xxx";

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

$data = array(
    'where' => array(
        'objectId' => array('$in' => array('e594OcnrBe'))
    ),
    'data' => array(
        'alert' => $text,
        'uri' => 'www.walla.com',
    ),
);

$_data = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
print_r($result);
die('finished!');
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ? What error(s) do you get ?

Comment: I did'nt get some errors. The code just doesnt work @jiboulex

Comment: If you get no errors, how do you see, that it is not working?

Comment: please, could you detail your problem, be more precise !

Comment: If it's on host server i getting this message "{"result":true} {"result":true} finished!", and when I runing the code on wamp server I dont get this message.

Comment: Is this the real code or something you put together as an example

Comment: It is the real code, I just changed the API_KEY @RiggsFolly

Comment: What relevance is `'uri' => 'www.walla.com'` is that referencing your live site

Comment: But its not your development site I assume! So if that is where responses are being sent.... could that be the problem

Comment: No its not my development site. but on host server it's working. I am trying to send a push notification using Parse API  `$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';`

Comment: But is that telling the `api.parse.com` site where to send some sort of reply?

Comment: No, its telling to api.parse.com to send push notification, And when i'm clicking on the notification automaticlly it's open www.walla.com @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working! 
i putted this code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```